# How to use pop and ret in MASM

Tags: c, memory-management, x86, masm, cpu-registers

I have recently started learning x86 Assembly using the MASM language.

I am using the Udemy course "x86 Assembly Language From Ground Up" by Isreal Gbati to learn.

The code below is from a lesson in the course, (It's not code that I came up with). This function is called by main in a C program. Here it is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern int AdderASM(int a, int b, int c);

int main(void)
{
    int a = 17;
    int b = 11;
    int c = 14;
    int sum = AdderASM(a, b, c);

    printf("A = %d\n", a);
    printf("B = %d\n", b);
    printf("C = %d\n", c);

    printf("SUM FROM ASSEMBLY FUNCTION = %d\n", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

And here is the assembly:

```
.386
.model flat, c

.code

AdderASM    PROC

            PUSH EBP             
            MOV EBP, ESP        

            MOV EAX, [EBP+8]     
            MOV ECX, [EBP+12]   
            MOV EDX, [EBP+16]   

            ADD EAX, ECX        
            ADD EAX, EDX        

            POP EBP

            RET

AdderASM    ENDP
            END
```

I don't understand the following:

When we use `pop`, from what I understand is kind of like using `free()` in C. Correct me if I am wrong

So why are we only using pop on the EBP register? Shouldn't we pop the ECX and EDX registers as well?

I know that in a C function, pointers that are allocated memory by `malloc()` need to be freed before the end of the function. The registers used are all general purpose 32 bit registers, but EBP has a special use as a stack-frame pointer. Is this why it needs to be freed?

Also, I understand that `ret` is used at the end of the procedure, but how do we know that this function is returning a value at all?

To better explain my question, here is the same function written in C:

```
int AdderClang(int a, int b, int c)
{
    return a + b + c;
}
```

If I only put `return;` Instead of `return a + b + c;` I don't know exactly what would happen but it wouldn't be the intended result. We can also tell that this C function returns an int because it tells us that in the declaration.

All of this may be explained later in the course, and I'm sure the answers to my questions are simple. However, I am trying to go slowly to make sure I understand what I am doing. And yes, I know that Assembly is not C, so comparing the 2 languages like I have may not be the right approach, but I am learning Assembly to better understand the memory management stuff in C.

Thank you all for your time!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> When we use `pop`, from what I understand is kind of like using `free()` in C.

That's not really the case. `push x` copies `x` on the top of the stack, and moves the stack pointer so that the new top is below the pushed value (remember that on x86, the stack grows downwards in memory). `pop x` does the opposite: copies the top of the stack into `x`, and then moves the stack pointer so that the new top is above the popped value (i.e. the value is removed from the stack).

Effectively, the pseudo-C equivalent would be this:

```
void push(int x) {
  --esp;
  *esp = x;
}

void pop(int *x) {
  *x = *esp;
  ++esp;
}
```

Therefore, `pop ebp` does not mean "clean the `ebp` register", but it means "pop a value from the stack and store it in the `ebp` register." Since we previously pushed `ebp`, this is just reverting it as part of ending our function.

---

> Also, I understand that `ret` is used at the end of the procedure, but how do we know that this function is returning a value at all?

You could say that in assembler world, every function is returning a value. The calling convention specifies how values are returned. On x86, the return value is stored in the `eax` register. So `ret` jumps to where the function was called from, and whatever is in `eax` at that time is what the caller gets as the return value. That's why the function computes the sum in `eax`, so that it's right where the caller will expect it.

Again, in pseudo-C, you could imagine a normal C `return` statement is implemented kind of like this:

```
void return(int x) {
  eax = x;
  ret;
}
```

Comment: Another way to say this is that push/pop at the start/end of a function is a way to save/restore your caller's register value, around your own use of it.